# how to parse xml element node susing pig script?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, hadoop, apache-pig

I am using pig latin for a large XML dump. I am trying to get the value of the xml nodes like location and temp_c in pig latin. The file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet href="latest_ob.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<current_observation version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.weather.gov/view/current_observation.xsd">
    <credit>NOAA's National Weather Service</credit>
    <credit_URL>http://weather.gov/</credit_URL>
    <image>
        <url>http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif</url>
        <title>NOAA's National Weather Service</title>
        <link>http://weather.gov</link>
    </image>
    <suggested_pickup>15 minutes after the hour</suggested_pickup>
    <suggested_pickup_period>60</suggested_pickup_period>
    <location>Unknown Station</location>
    <station_id>51WH0</station_id>
    <observation_time>Last Updated on Dec 23 2014, 11:00 pm LST</observation_time>
        <observation_time_rfc822>Tue, 23 Dec 2014 23:00:00 +1000</observation_time_rfc822>
    <temperature_string>71.4 F (21.9 C)</temperature_string>
    <temp_f>71.4</temp_f>
    <temp_c>21.9</temp_c>
    <water_temp_f>75.9</water_temp_f>
    <water_temp_c>24.4</water_temp_c>
    <wind_string>North at 24.6 MPH (21.38 KT)</wind_string>
    <wind_dir>North</wind_dir>
    <wind_degrees>20</wind_degrees>
    <wind_mph>24.6</wind_mph>
    <wind_gust_mph>0.0</wind_gust_mph>
    <wind_kt>21.38</wind_kt>
    <pressure_string>1015.0 mb</pressure_string>
    <pressure_mb>1015.0</pressure_mb>
    <dewpoint_string>58.1 F (14.5 C)</dewpoint_string>
    <dewpoint_f>58.1</dewpoint_f>
    <dewpoint_c>14.5</dewpoint_c>
</current_observation>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it will help you, try this out.

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

A =  LOAD 'xmls/your_file.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('current_observation') as (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'current_observation/location'), XPath(x, 'current_observation/temp_c');
dump B;
```

Comment: Hi ravi I tried that but there are some attributes after root element due to that it is not able to dump the result. and every xml file is containing the same format.  
     <current_observation version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.weather.gov/view/current_observation.xsd">

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 data = LOAD '/path/your_file.xml'
       USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.StreamingXMLLoader(
          'current_observation',
          'credit, credit_URL, image, suggested_pickup, suggested_pickup_period, location, station_id, observation_time,temp_f, temp_c, water_temp_f, water_temp_c, wind_string, wind_dir, wind_degrees, wind_mph, wind_gust_mph, wind_kt, pressure_string, pressure_mb, dewpoint_string, dewpoint_f, dewpoint_c'
       ) AS (
           credit:    {(attr:map[], content:chararray)}
           credit_URL: {(attr:map[], content:chararray)}

        .
        .
        .
       );

dump data;
```

Comment: getting these errors :
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.StreamingXMLLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
 at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:682)
 at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1320)
 ... 26 more
2014-12-29 12:26:40,739 [main] ERROR

Comment: org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.StreamingXMLLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/hduser/Desktop/pig_1419836199018.log

Comment: which version of pig you are using now.

Comment: If you want use **StreamingXMLLoader** pig version should be 0.13 or above.

Comment: hi ravi I am using pig-0.14.0

Comment: then it must recognize the **StreamingXMLLoader**, or just checkout src folder in pig-0.14.0.src  **pig-0.14.0-src/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/xml/Xpath.java** see that UDF you can understand.

Comment: or copy that java file, make jar and use it as UDF.

Comment: Hi ravi thank you for your reply and suggestions but I am getting same error ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.StreamingXMLLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]